# How do I get the output from a method back into the main method in Java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    public class Assignment51
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          /*
          Four Categories are used as a basis for compiling a rating:
          1. Percentage of completions
          2. Average yards gained
          3. Percentage of touchdown passes per attempt
          4. Percentage of interceptions per attempt
          */

          // DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.000");

          String input;        //get user input
          String name;         //player name
          int completion;      //number of completions in percentages
          int yardsGained;     //number of yards gained
          int tdpasses;        //number of touchdown passes
          int interceptions;   //number of interceptions
          int attempts;        //number of attempts
          int yards;           //number of yards
          double score;        //passer score
          double totalScore;   //total score
          double totalPoints;  //total award points
          double total;        //total sum

          //get player name
          name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the player name");


          //Creating Methods

          PctCompletion();
          AvgYardsGain();
          PctTouchdown();
          PctInterceptions();     


          //RETURN TO MAIN METHOD
          double PctCompletion, AvgYardsGain, PctTouchdown, PctInterceptions;

          totalPoints = PctCompletion +  AvgYardsGain + PctTouchdown + PctInterceptions;

          total = (totalPoints / 6) * 100;

          //OUTPUT      
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "total points: " + totalPoints + "\ntotal: " + total);
          //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name + " earned a total of " + total + " award points.\n"); //GET HELP WITH OUTPUT
       }


       //calling the PctCompletion method.
       public static double PctCompletion()
       { 
          String input;                     //user input
          int num1;                         //first input
          int num2;                         //second input total amount of passes
          double percentComp = 0.0;         //percent completed. num1/num2 = percentComp
          double pointRatingComp = 0.0;     //Completions point rating
          double awardPoints1 = 0.0;         //awarded points +/- 2.375

          input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the TOTAL number of passes");
          num2  = Integer.parseInt(input);

          input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the number of COMPLETED passes");
          num1 = Integer.parseInt(input);

          percentComp = ((num1 / num2) * 100);

          //point rating
          pointRatingComp = ((percentComp - 30) * .05);

          if (pointRatingComp < 0 && percentComp < 30.0)
             awardPoints1  = 0.0;

          if (pointRatingComp > 2.375 && percentComp > 77.5)
             awardPoints1 = 2.375;

          return awardPoints1;      
       }


       //calling the AvgYardsGain method
       public static double AvgYardsGain()
       {
          String input;                     //user input
          int num1;                         //first input total yards
          int num2;                         //second input total attempts
          double percentYard = 0.0;         //percent completed. num1/num2 = percentYard
          double pointRatingYard = 0.0;     //Yards point rating
          double awardPoints2 = 0.0;        //awarded points +/- 2.375

          input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the TOTAL number of attempts");
          num2 = Integer.parseInt(input);

          input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the TOTAL amount of yards");
          num1 = Integer.parseInt(input);

          percentYard = ((num1 / num2) * 100); 

          //point rating
          pointRatingYard = ((percentYard - 3) * .25);

          if (pointRatingYard < 0 && percentYard < 3)
             awardPoints2 = 0;

          if (pointRatingYard > 2.375 && percentYard > 12.5)
             awardPoints2 = 2.375;

          return awardPoints2;
       }


       //calling the PctTouchdown method
       public static double PctTouchdown()
       {
          String input;                      //user input
          int num1;                          //input total number of touchdowns
          int num2;                          //input total amount of attempts
          double percentTD = 0.0;            //percent completed. num1/num2 = percentTD
          double pointRatingTD = 0.0;        //touchdowns point rating
          double awardPoints3 = 0.0;         //awarded points +/- 2.375

          input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the TOTAL number of pass ATTEMPTS");
          num2 = Integer.parseInt(input);

          input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the TOTAL number of TOUCHDOWNS");
          num1 = Integer.parseInt(input);

          percentTD = ((num1 / num2) * 100);

          //point rating
          pointRatingTD = (percentTD * .2);

          if (pointRatingTD > 2.375 && percentTD > 11.875)
             awardPoints3 = 2.375;

          return awardPoints3;     
       }


       //calling the PctInterceptions method
       public static double PctInterceptions()
       {
          String input;                     //user input
          int num1;                         //input total amount of interceptions
          int num2;                         //input total amount of attempts
          double percentINT = 0.0;         //percent completed. num1/num2 = percentComp
          double pointRatingINT = 0.0;     //Completions point rating
          double awardPoints4 = 0.0;         //awarded points +/- 2.375

          input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the TOTAL number of pass ATTEMPTS");
          num2 = Integer.parseInt(input);

          input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the TOTAL amount of INTERCEPTIONS");
          num1 = Integer.parseInt(input);

          percentINT = ((num1 / num2) * 100);

          //point rating
          pointRatingINT = 2.375 - (percentINT * .25);

          if (pointRatingINT < 0 && percentINT > 9.5)
             awardPoints4 = 0;
          else
             awardPoints4 = 2.375;

          return awardPoints4;
       }
    }
```

I want the return values (awardpoints) to do a calculation from the values they received from the methods. However, I am getting an error when I do so.
This is the part of the code i'm having trouble with.

```
//RETURN TO MAIN METHOD
              double PctCompletion, AvgYardsGain, PctTouchdown, PctInterceptions;

              totalPoints = PctCompletion +  AvgYardsGain + PctTouchdown + PctInterceptions;

              total = (totalPoints / 6) * 100;
```

Comment: You failed to tell us the error message you are receiving.  Without that it is hard to help you.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: `Assignment51.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
      totalPoints = awardPoints1 + awardPoints2 + awardPoints3 + awardPoints4;
                    ^
  symbol:   variable awardPoints1
  location: class Assignment51
`

Comment: Just something I've spotted in your code documentation. before each method, you write "//calling the xxx method". Maybe it's to picky, but you don't actually call the method there. you implement it. The calling of the method happens, in your case, in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parenthesis when calling a function

```
totalPoints = PctCompletion +  AvgYardsGain + PctTouchdown + PctInterceptions;
```

should be corrected to

```
totalPoints = PctCompletion() +  AvgYardsGain() + PctTouchdown() + PctInterceptions();
```